# Error: No browser on device. What are you doing?

Tags: samsung, browser, system-error, android-10, application-error

I am using Android 10. Samsung One UI 2.0.

I have installed: google-chrome, firefox in my android. But, when I click on external url on various apps, I get this error very often: `No browser on device. What are you doing?`. And on the other times I don't get this error.

How can I resolve this issue? Any suggestions?

---

@Robert

[image]

Comment: May be the error message is not about your web browser but about the "WebView component", this is the web browser component that can be used by other apps e.g. to display web pages. This WebView can be provided by a web browser app like Chrome or a special WebView app. Check Settings -> Development menu which app is selected to provide the "WebView implementation" (not sure if this is the exact name).

Comment: @Robert I did what you said. Please see the question I have updated it with the screenshot.

Comment: WebView looks good, that does seem to be an issue. Then it might be that an app has somehow captured the default "Browser app". You can try resetting the default apps as shown here: https://www.samsung.com/au/support/mobile-devices/reset-default-apps/

Comment: @Robert I did what you said. The default browser was already defined as Firefox. I have reset the settings. Would let you know if it occurs again.